# Swift 3 add a custom border to one of the edges of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3

I had a code snippet as shown below that used to work just fine until I migrated to Swift 3, to be able to draw a border around the UIView. I just want to be able to do this at the bottom of the UIView.

```
    let border = CALayer()
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.basicDetailsView.frame.height - 2, width: self.basicDetailsView.frame.width, height: 2)
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray().cgColor

    self.basicDetailsView.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, it just doesn't end up drawing a border anymore!

Comment: @EmbCoder Did you end up solving this?

Comment: @sdasdadas I had to revert back to Swift 2 due to some other constraints so I did not pursue this further. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems performing calculations with frame sizes in viewDidLoad and awakeFromNib.  Everything worked dandily in swift 2.3 and then things disappeared in swift 3

This post helped me: [cornerRadius stopped working in Swift 2.3 / iOS 10 / Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503661/cornerradius-stopped-working-in-swift-2-3-ios-10-xcode-8/39515254#39515254)

You can move the code to viewDidAppear, or call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() beforehand

I opted for the latter.