# cornerRadius stopped working in Swift 2.3 / iOS 10 / Xcode 8

Tags: swift3, ios10, swift2

I have a `cornerRadius` set on a `UIView` and a `UIImageView` inside the same `UIView`. I am calculating the corner radius with `RockProfileView.frame.size.height / 2` but the UIView stopped showing in iOS 10.

After further checking i found the value of `RockProfileView.frame.size.height / 2` is coming out to be 1000.0 while the width and height constraint is set to 64.0

When I hardcoded the `RockProfileView.layer.cornerRadius = 32` to 64/2 it works just fine.

What could be the issue ?

Full code:

```
    RockProfileView.layer.cornerRadius = RockProfileView.frame.size.height / 2
    RockProfileView.clipsToBounds = true
    RockProgressView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: It's a question of where you're doing this. If you're doing it in `init` or `viewDidLoad`, for example, the constraints may not have been applied yet, and thus the location of the views is still indeterminate. You can solve this problem by doing it later in the view build process, such as `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Hi @Rob: Thanks for the reply, I have tried it out by moving the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and it works like charm :) Thank you!

Comment: I also had to fix my custom buttons due to the update. I was applying the corner radius in the ViewWillAppear. Applying the cornerRadius in the ViewDidAppear isn't a pretty solution though. Strange that this isn't possible anymore...

Comment: Nevermind, the viewDidLayoutSubviews is the new way to go.

Comment: self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
Add this line before setting corner radius.

Comment: I spent most of the morning on the same issue. Has anyone found any documentation on this change?

Comment: apple is totally bullshit... without any documentation such changes... I were changing cornerRadius in awakeFromNib, caused backgroundColor to disappear, i dont understand.. what is connection between backgroundcolor of button and cornerradius. Totally bullshit

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As answered by Rob, I've moved the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and the problem is fixed.

OR 
Adding `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before your code in `viewDidLoad` also solves the issue.

In case of UITableViewCell, Inside `awakeFromNib` add `[self layoutIfNeeded];` before updating the corner radius should solve all the issues.

Comment: This worked for me, but for a constraint update. Worked in iOS 9, broke in iOS 10.

Comment: ViewDidAppear causes visible pop-in of view attributes like corners. I had the same problem and fixed it in the end with YPK's  answer. I think that should be the accepted one really as ViewDidAppear has nasty side effects.

Comment: @Ryan: Adding self.view.layoutIfNeeded() before your code also solves the problem in viewDidLoad itself.

Comment: Using code inside viewdidAppear code working fine without using self.view.layoutIfNeeded().

Comment: [self layoutIfNeeded]; BEFORE updating the corner radius should solve all the issues.

Answer (score 8):

I were done this code in `awakeFromNib`, but after upgrading to ios 10+xcode 8, it stopped working.

Then i moved this code to `layoutSubViews` method. Then it worked.

Hoping, this will be be useful to you.

If you want to still do this in awakefromnib, then do this after putting some delay(by using dispatch_after or NSOperatinQueue or performSelectorWithDelay)

Answer (score 4):

If it is inside your one of `ViewControllers`, instead of moving all layer operations to `viewDidLayer`, move that code inside `DispatchQueue`. This worked for me:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let layer = self.signUpBtn.layer
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            layer.borderWidth = 2 / UIScreen.main.scale
        }
```

Hope this helps for you

Answer (score 3):

New one thing into XCode8 we can't directly set the cornerRadius of the layer.

When you want to apply cornerRadius of UIView need to add one line of code before applying cornerRadius.

yourButton.layoutIfNeeded()

Example into Objective C.

```
[yourButton layoutIfNeeded];
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.frame.size.height/2;
[[yourButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
Example into Swift3

self.layoutIfNeeded()
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2.0
yourButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

For me what it worked was first call layoutIfNeeded and later on set cornerRadius

Answer (score 1):

swift 3

I will try this code to define corner radius of UIImageview

```
 imgProfile.layer.cornerRadius = imgProfile.frame.size.width / 2
            imgProfile.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Marked with `@IBInspectable` in swift (or IBInspectable in Objective-C), they are easily editable in Interface Builder’s attributes inspector panel.
You can directly set **cornerRadius** in attributes inspector

```
extension UIView {

  @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {

   get{
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, iOS 10 only. I found that ViewDidLayoutSubviews or ViewDidLoad (possibly others too but I didn't check) only worked if I wrapped the layout code in the dispatch queue as YPK suggested.

I am using Xamarin so the syntax is a bit different:

```
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            SetYourViewProperties();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run it on the main thread for it to work.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [imageView.layer setCornerRadius:4];
       [imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a previous answer, adding `self.layoutIfNeeded()` before changing the corner radius worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.2 Solution**

In case anyone still having this problem, I solved the problem by rounding the cells (or any of its subviews) in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if (tableView.visibleCells.count > 0) {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            let customCell = cell as! CustomCell
            // Use any rounding method you use
            customCell.exampleSubview.roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 6) 
            customCell.exampleSubview.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In WWDC 2016 | What's New in Auto Layout, Apple recommend a way of autolayout named

> Incrementally Adopting Autolayout

It means if the layout is easy, you can use autoresizing. And it will translate to constraints at run time.

So one of the solutions is use autoresizing, and you can get right frame about the view in anytime. But the premise is the autoresizing can satisfy your layout

Comment: @JRafaelM Maybe I should explain in detailed. Now almost every one use autolayout to ensure the position and bounds. After that, you will find the frame of views is not right in viewDidLoad which cause the cornerRadius wrong. However, if you use autoresizing, you won't have that problem