# Migration to Swift 3 from Swift 2.2 broke my custom subclassed UIButton's setting the backgroundcolor

Tags: uibutton, background-color, swift3

I can't believe I cannot figure this out. After migrating to Swift 3 yesterday I got everything but one thing working.

I created a custom button subclassing from UIButton. Upon selection I want to change the background color. This worked in Swift 2.2. Now I cant change the backgroundcolor when the button's been pressed. I can still change the background color of a UIButton, but not on the subclassed button.

What changed in Swift 3, am I missing something? The color for setTitleColor does change by the way.

Code:

```
func selectButton(_ button: CustomButton) {
    button.isSelected = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .selected)
}
```

When I add printstatements, I see that the output is different, but the view (color) hasn't changed.

```
print("CHANGE COLOR FROM: \(button.backgroundColor)")
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .selected)
button.setNeedsDisplay()
print("CHANGE COLOR TO: \(button.backgroundColor)")
```

Output:

```
CHANGE COLOR FROM: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1)
CHANGE COLOR TO: Optional(UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1)
```

Comment: a little code snippet, maybe? I have tens of designable `UIViews` (incl. `UIButtons` as well), I did the migration just yesterday, and none of the desinbable views were broken; so it would be great to see what you have done, because that issue does not seem to be a generic one.

Comment: Hmm, thats good news (it's still possible) and bad (I seem to be doing something wrong). Ill edit the question.

Comment: is it the real code? how can be sure `Color.bePrEPared.red()` is not `nil`?

Comment: The crazy thing is, the titleColor does change.

Comment: A regular UIColor doesn't work either. Ill change for clarification

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that the problem was setting cornerRadius was somehow messing up my button. Removing the cornerRadius or changing it in viewDidAppear fixed the problem.

Also described in [cornerRadius stopped working in Swift 2.3 / iOS 10 / Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503661/cornerradius-stopped-working-in-swift-2-3-ios-10-xcode-8)